# How to hold Alphanumeric keys from keyboard using TestStack.White Framework

Tags: ui-automation, white-framework

I'm familiar with the command `Keyboard.Instance.HoldKey(KeyboardInput.SpecialKeys.CONTROL);` as well as `Keyboard.Instance.Enter("Z");`, but I don't seem to be able to find a way to hold down alphanumeric keys using this. Am I missing something? HoldKey seems to only take SpecialKeys.

I'm wanting to hold down both CTRL and Z at the same time. I don't want to merely press the Z key.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This so far as I can see is not possible with White.

Instead, you could use [Input Simulator](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com) to do this, which  has a SimulateKeyDown and SimulateKeyUp method available for every key.